# How deduce $\prod_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2} \sin^2 \frac{k\pi}{n} =\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$ from $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin \frac{k\pi}{n} =\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, summation

I know that $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin \frac{k\pi}{n} =\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$ for any integer $n \geq 1$ is true.

Now, suppose that $n$ is odd, how show
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2} \sin^2 \frac{k\pi}{n} =\frac{n}{2^{n-1}} ?
$$
I read in a book (Bourbaki) that the first equality implies the second.

Comment: Hint:$\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$ and $\sin(\pi/2)=1.$

Comment: It should be probably $n/2-1$ instead of $(n-1)/2$ in the second equation.

Comment: Corrected. I replace even by odd. Sorry.

Comment: The hint of @ThomasAndrews works in this case as well.

Comment: Yes, the same hint applies, you just no longer need $\sin\frac\pi2=1$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Please write what you have tried to solve the problem. You have four close votes for this issue. I personally won't vote though because nobody told you this. @ThomasAndrews You could make your hint an answer because it makes the problem straightforward.